# set theory - simplify expresion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

i know its an easy question but i got confused so i drew a picture to explain.

(A  U  B) \ B   =  ?

is the answer A or  A \ B?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeW2B.png

( A U B) \ B = A union B without B

[which one?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeW2B.png)

Comment: It may help if you remember that in the context of having a universal set you have $E\setminus F = E\cap F^c$.  So, you have $(A\cup B)\setminus B = (A\cup B)\cap B^c = (A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap B^c) = (A\cap B^c)\cup (\emptyset) = A\cap B^c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove all of $B$ so the answer is $A\setminus B$

If you had $A \cup (B \setminus B)$ that would be $A \cup \emptyset = A$

So your expression 'A union B without B' is ambiguous between exactly the two different interpretions you indicate! However, using parentheses, the ambiguity goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $A\setminus B  = A \cap B^c $. So, you are looking for $(A \cup B) \cap B^c$. Since $B^c \subset A\cup B$, your answer is $A \setminus B$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in(A\cup B)/ B$, then $x\in A\cup B$, but not in $B$, so if $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. But by hip. it doesn't belong to $B$, so $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$. It is: $A/B$. (Well, to get the other contention you have to see a bit logic thing, but it is easy!)